# View a PDF file from my Android app

Tags: android, pdf

I want to use this [AndroidPdfViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) library in my app, but during building it gives me the following error:

[image: Error message]

How do I overcome this?

Comment: it will be good if you create issue in that repository the owner will reply you there

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the connection to the maven repositories was refused. Make sure there are no typos in your `compile` statement.

If that doesn't help, you should create an issue on that github page, where the creator might be able to help you.